# efficient use of R data.table and unique()

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a more efficient query than the following

```
DT[, list(length(unique(OrderNo)) ),customerID]
```

to refine a LONG format table with customer id's, order number and product line items, meaning that there will be duplicate rows with the same order id if a customer has purchased more than 1 item in that transaction.

Trying to work out unique purchases. `length()` gives a count of all order id's by customer ID including duplicates, looking for just the unique number.

## Edit from here:

Here is some dummy code. Ideally what i am looking for is the output from the first query using the `unique()`.

```
df <- data.frame(
             customerID=as.factor(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4))),
             product=as.factor(c(rep("widget",2),rep("otherstuff",5))),
             orderID=as.factor(c("xyz","xyz","abd","qwe","rty","yui","poi")),
             OrderDate=as.Date(c("2013-07-01","2013-07-01","2013-07-03","2013-06-01","2013-06-02","2013-06-03","2013-07-01"))
             )

DT.eg <- as.data.table(df)
#Gives unique order counts
DT.eg[, list(orderlength = length(unique(orderID)) ),customerID]
#Gives counts of all orders by customer
DT.eg[,.SD, keyby=list(orderID, customerID)][, .N, by=customerID]

         ^
         |
  This should be .N, not .SD  ~ R.S.
```

Comment: @Ricardo, just noticed that, yep, that did the trick. cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you are trying to count the number of unique purchases per customer, use

```
 DT[, .N, keyby=list(customerId, OrderNo)][, .N, by=customerId]
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks Ricardo!!

Comment: Actually, sorry Ricardo, was only assessing the head output, diving into the table I found it is still giving me the count of all line item orders rather than unique count of orders. I have edited my original post with some code to reproduce. the unique () ends up killing the process on a large customer base.

Comment: Um, I don't see any "unique" in Ricardo's answer. Maybe you're looking for `DT.eg[,.N,by='orderID,customerID'][,sum(N),by=customerID]` ?

Comment: @digdeep, have a look at what you are using and have a look at my answer.   Two different things ;)   Replace `.SD` with `.N` (or with any constant for that matter) and you are all set

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.9.6 (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015), `data.table` has gained the helper function `uniqueN()` which is equivalent to `length(unique(x))` but much faster (according to [`data.table` NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-3)).

With this,

```
DT.eg[, list(orderlength = length(unique(orderID)) ),customerID]
```

and

```
DT.eg[,.N, keyby=list(orderID, customerID)][, .N, by=customerID]
```

can be rewritten as

```
DT.eg[, .(orderlength = uniqueN(orderID)), customerID]
```

> ```
>    customerID orderlength
> 1:          A           2
> 2:          B           4
> ```